# Wait for redux to load the data

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to extract an object from redux. I want to display the value when it is loaded. I don't know how to do it.

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
```

This is the code I wrote. It extracts the value from redux but initially, it is undefined. I want to perform a function when the value gets loaded completely. How can I do it?

Comment: You could use an `useEffect` hook with a dependency on `user` that runs some logic when it updates. What have you tried? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by using conditional rendering for example:

```
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user);
{user && user.map(item=>(
<div>
<ul>
<li>{item.name}</li>
<ul>
</div>
)}
```

so if user is true then only map the user array, try this code in your render method of JSX.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly what does the reducer state look like and also if you have named the reducer user as well as there being a user object in the initial state then you are going to have to look at using

```
like this 
const { user } = useSelector((state) => state.user);

or like this
const user = useSelector((state) => state.user.user);

then where you use it if the user is undefined 

and you want to render the user object once the user data has successfully updated

something like 

<div>
{user && user.name}
{user && user.age}
{user && user.height}
</div>

or if you want to show all the data and there are no embedded properties

you could do something like 

<div>
{Object.keys(user).length > 0 &&
Object.keys(user)
.map((key) => 
<div>{user[key]}</div>)
}
</div>
```

Comment: Remember it all depends on how your redux state is name like user.user etc